# SQL Server very slow in dev but not in production

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've been battling with SQL Server (14.0.2027.2) timing out in my dev environment for the simplest of queries.

This not only affects the web application that I develop but also performing simple functions in SQL Server Management Studio (v15.0.18.131.0) e.g.

1. expanding the "Tables" or "Stored procedures" nodes (contains around 100 tables and 400 procedures) can take up to 2-3 minutes
2. Right Click > Modify a Stored Procedure can take 2-3 minutes for the ALTER PROCEDURE query window to open.

I'm running on a Core i7 with 4 SAMSUNG SSDs.  The problem is consistent on my development environment and I regularly take a download of the production database and restore to dev.

So you are going to ask what I've tried:

- I'm struggling know how to use tools such as `sp_WhoIsActive` as everything locks up in SQL Server Management Studio while the UI is blocked by the slow processes described in 1 and 2 above.
- I've reinstalled Management Studio (didn't fix the problem)
- I've looked at my physical disks: as a dev environment, the database data and logs are stored on a 256GB Samsung SSD with Bitlocker enabled and it is exclusively used just for the database data and logs.  I previously had the logs on a separate (non-bitlocker non-OS drive) but the problem was still occurring then.
- I'm taking backups from our two production environments and restoring it to the dev environment.  Both backup and restore are not delayed like the queries are.  The database is 5GB and good indexing and RI and works well in the production environments despite being a similar configuration (one runs on SSD, the other on HDD).

I suspect the issue arose after upgrading from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2019 but that was several months ago now so I cannot be sure.

I also really suspect this isn't an issue around the database tables, indexes and relationships but with some configuration at the SQL Server level.  Any advise would be welcome.

EDIT: `@@VERSION` comes back with "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor) "

EDIT: I've checked autoclose across the board.  On live, test and dev, each database has AUTO CLOSE set to FALSE.

EDIT: Checked Configuration of SQL server (used SQLServerManager14.exe):

- SQL Server: Integration Services 14: Running / Automatic
- SQL Server: Running / Automatic
- SQL Server Analysis Services: Running / Automatic
- SQL Server Browser: Stopped / Other
- SQL Server Agent: Stopped / Manual

Native Client protocols:

- Shared Memory: [1st] Enabled
- TCP/IP: [2nd] Enabled
- Named Pipes: [3rd] Enabled

Network Configuration protocols:

- Shared Memory:  Enabled
- Named Pipes: Disabled
- TCP/IP: Enabled

EDIT: Querying **sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks** view when waiting for a Right Click Stored Procedure > Modify to open up (took about 45 seconds to open up the SP): (ran a few times but this is one sample; `blocking_task_address blocking_session_id blocking_exec_context_id resource_description` were all NULL)

```
1> SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
2> go
waiting_task_address session_id exec_context_id wait_duration_ms     wait_type                                                    resource_address  
-------------------- ---------- --------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------
0x000001A31701C8C8           12               0                 8707 XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT                                           NULL              
0x000001A31701CCA8           18               0                  102 ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE                                          0x000000240F7FE950
0x000001A31701D848            9               0              8833279 BROKER_TRANSMITTER                                           NULL              
0x000001A317027088            4               0                    1 LAZYWRITER_SLEEP                                             NULL              
0x000001A317027468           20               0              4509358 BROKER_EVENTHANDLER                                          NULL              
0x000001A31702ECA8           19               0              1209983 CHECKPOINT_QUEUE                                             0x000000240FBFEB00
0x000001A31702F088            7               0                  544 SLEEP_TASK                                                   NULL              
0x000001A317036CA8            6               0              8833175 KSOURCE_WAKEUP                                               NULL              
0x000001A3170368C8           17               0               134353 SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP                                  0x0000000000000001
0x000001A317037848           34               0              8833279 BROKER_TRANSMITTER                                           NULL              
0x000001A31703ECA8            5               0                 3714 REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH                                  0x000000240FFFEBD0
0x000001A31703F088           36               0                  215 SLEEP_TASK                                                   NULL              
0x000001A3170468C8         NULL            NULL              8834648 XTP_PREEMPTIVE_TASK                                          NULL              
0x000001A317046CA8            8               0                  118 SLEEP_TASK                                                   NULL              
0x000001A317047C28           35               0                  322 HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION                           NULL              
0x000001A31704E8C8            1               0              8834648 WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT                                           NULL              
0x000001A31704ECA8         NULL            NULL                14105 QDS_PERSIST_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP                             NULL              
0x000001A317056CA8           11               0                 4190 XE_TIMER_EVENT                                               NULL              
0x000001A317057088         NULL            NULL              8834640 QDS_ASYNC_QUEUE                                              NULL              
0x000001A317057468           21               0              8834376 HADR_NOTIFICATION_DEQUEUE                                    0x00000024115FF3D0
0x000001A3176904E8           10               0                  102 SLEEP_TASK                                                   NULL              
0x000001A311A204E8            2               0                   82 LOGMGR_QUEUE                                                 0x000000240EDFD170
0x000001A311A384E8            3               0                   28 DIRTY_PAGE_POLL                                              NULL              
0x000001A3103304E8         NULL            NULL                 4711 CLR_AUTO_EVENT                                               NULL              
0x000001A31034A4E8         NULL            NULL                 4711 CLR_AUTO_EVENT                                               NULL              
0x000001A30FA064E8           15               0                 1137 SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP                             NULL              

(26 rows affected)
```

EDIT: I've run SQL Profiler while opening a Stored Procedure for editing.  It took around 90 seconds to open.  Profile blocked on this particular query for 86.43 seconds (it's a long one!):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
sp.name AS [Name],
sp.object_id AS [ID],
sp.create_date AS [CreateDate],
sp.modify_date AS [DateLastModified],
ISNULL(ssp.name, N'''') AS [Owner],
CAST(case when sp.principal_id is null then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsSchemaOwned],
SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id) AS [Schema],
CAST(
 case 
    when sp.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = sp.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N''microsoft_database_tools_support'') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sp.object_id,N''ExecIsAnsiNullsOn''),0) AS bit) AS [AnsiNullsStatus],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sp.object_id,N''ExecIsQuotedIdentOn''),0) AS bit) AS [QuotedIdentifierStatus],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sp.object_id, N''IsSchemaBound''),0) AS bit) AS [IsSchemaBound],
CAST(CASE WHEN ISNULL(smsp.definition, ssmsp.definition) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsEncrypted],
CAST(ISNULL(smsp.is_recompiled, ssmsp.is_recompiled) AS bit) AS [Recompile],
case when amsp.object_id is null then N'''' else asmblsp.name end AS [AssemblyName],
case when amsp.object_id is null then N'''' else amsp.assembly_class end AS [ClassName],
case when amsp.object_id is null then N'''' else amsp.assembly_method end AS [MethodName],
case when amsp.object_id is null then case isnull(smsp.execute_as_principal_id, -1) when -1 then 1 when -2 then 2 else 3 end else case isnull(amsp.execute_as_principal_id, -1) when -1 then 1 when -2 then 2 else 3 end end AS [ExecutionContext],
case when amsp.object_id is null then ISNULL(user_name(smsp.execute_as_principal_id),N'''') else user_name(amsp.execute_as_principal_id) end AS [ExecutionContextPrincipal],
CAST(ISNULL(spp.is_auto_executed,0) AS bit) AS [Startup],
CASE WHEN sp.type = N''P'' THEN 1 WHEN sp.type = N''PC'' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS [ImplementationType],
CAST(CASE sp.type WHEN N''RF'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [ForReplication],
ISNULL(sm.uses_native_compilation,0) AS [IsNativelyCompiled]
FROM
sys.all_objects AS sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS ssp ON ssp.principal_id = ISNULL(sp.principal_id, (OBJECTPROPERTY(sp.object_id, ''OwnerId'')))
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smsp ON smsp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmsp ON ssmsp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.assembly_modules AS amsp ON amsp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.assemblies AS asmblsp ON asmblsp.assembly_id = amsp.assembly_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.procedures AS spp ON spp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_sql_modules AS sm ON sm.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE
(sp.type = @_msparam_0 OR sp.type = @_msparam_1 OR sp.type=@_msparam_2)and(sp.name=@_msparam_3 and SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id)=@_msparam_4)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_4 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'P',@_msparam_1=N'RF',@_msparam_2=N'PC',@_msparam_3=N'CreateItem_FlightCheck',@_msparam_4=N'Assessment'
```

EDIT: In case my system databases are at fault, they are stored on the OS disk (SSD) of my dev environment:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1202-7717

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

15/07/2019  21:10    <DIR>          .
15/07/2019  21:10    <DIR>          ..
18/09/2019  13:32         5,636,096 master.mdf
18/09/2019  13:32         1,835,008 mastlog.ldf
18/09/2019  10:28         8,388,608 model.mdf
18/09/2019  13:32         8,388,608 modellog.ldf
18/09/2019  11:43        20,578,304 MSDBData.mdf
18/09/2019  13:32        20,578,304 MSDBLog.ldf
21/08/2018  01:34               778 MS_AgentSigningCertificate.cer
15/07/2019  21:10               778 MS_AgentSigningCertificate2DA7FDC4-1A16-487A-89A4-630444C694CA.cer
30/05/2019  09:53               778 MS_AgentSigningCertificate35C8E19E-8C24-4101-835E-D976260916A0.cer
15/05/2019  15:50               778 MS_AgentSigningCertificateAC01273F-89E4-48ED-8F9C-CF4A608AE064.cer
18/09/2019  12:58         8,388,608 tempdb.mdf
18/09/2019  13:31         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_2.ndf
18/09/2019  13:31         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_3.ndf
18/09/2019  13:31         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_4.ndf
18/09/2019  13:31         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_5.ndf
18/09/2019  13:31         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_6.ndf
18/09/2019  13:32         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_7.ndf
18/09/2019  13:10         8,388,608 tempdb_mssql_8.ndf
18/09/2019  13:32         8,388,608 templog.ldf
              19 File(s)    140,905,512 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  76,880,195,584 bytes free
```

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Please add the result of select @@version to your question. If your server is Express one you have a lot of limitations, for example, only 1Gb of RAM

Comment: maybe worth a read: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/99bbcb47-d4b5-4ec0-9e91-b1a23a655844/ssms-2012-extremely-slow-expanding-databases?forum=sqltools

Comment: @Tanner "I regularly take a download of the production database and restore to dev" means that autoclose option is the same on dev and prod

Comment: @sepupic - added.  @@VERSION comes back with "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor) "

Comment: @Tanner double checked what? That database option "autoclose" does not change with backup/restore???

Comment: I would also check the protocols enabled on SQL Server configuration for dev.

Comment: I've checked autoclose across the board.  On live, test and dev, each database has AUTO CLOSE set to FALSE.

Comment: @Chris Walsh Did you check sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks when your SSMS takes long time to open OE? What are the waits for its session?

Comment: @CetinBasoz - good point.  Humm.  I can't see Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager in my start menu (bloomin' microsoft!). I'm sure I've only got Shared Pipes active but I will need to check.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - Okay, I've added the configuration details at the end of my opening post. It looks like Shared Memory will be the default.  Thanks.

Comment: What about waits in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks?

Comment: Check the speed of a command-line opened trusted connection: `sqlcmd -S <server>`, then issue something simple like `SELECT 1`; `GO`. This should return instantaneously. If it does not, the next thing to try would be to log in with an SQL user/password instead -- if this is fast, the problem is integrated authentication, i.e. Kerberos. If both are slow just on connecting already, the likely culprit would be the network (firewall having a fit, third-party filtering tools, that sort of thing).

Comment: @supupic - Sorry, was getting around to that one.  As the Studio tool blocks when this expanding business is occuring, I guess I need to view `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` via `sqlcmd`?  Would that be sensible? Trying it now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Trivial queries such as this run fine. Just tried it for completion. No probs.  Even a SELECT * FROM [user] (100,000 rows) will work fine.

Comment: Management Studio is not particularly magical and also just issues queries, although those do end up a little more interesting than others. Try something like `sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?'', name from [?].sys.tables'` as a basic "fetch all table names" query. If this slows down on hitting particular databases that'd be interesting.

Comment: @supupic - I've added the results of the `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` view to my opening post while awaiting the SP to open up in Management Studio. Thanks.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this issue lies with the *master* database (which is on a different SSD to my application database files) that could be problem.  All my disks as SSDs but if a query of `sys.allobjects` with left outer joins with seven other sys tables is taking over a minute then could `master` be the problem?

Comment: @Chris Walsh I meant sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks wt in join with sys.dm_exec_sessions filtered by your session id or at least by is_user_process = 1  but in any case what you show us are only system processes

Comment: Did you try to follow the steps (even if not the good version) in this post :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b588653e-aa17-45bc-ae76-3cd309769b31/performance-issue-after-upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-is-anything-changed-with-optimizer-logic?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: @CyrilRebreyend - okay.  It looks a little out of my depth but I'll have a go:
Michelle Li's answer:
1. "After you upgrade - hardware requirements increased."  My dev env has 8GB RAM Core i7 with SSD so I don't think a version upgrade would produce such a detriment esp as dev PC is compatible with production.
2."Microsoft’s query processor team made changes to the new CE". I've got some idea on what Cardinality Estimation is but this is pretty deep - I would have to try look into this against a query but again, one of my two production servers is running the same version of SQL Svr.

Comment: 2a - Compatibility Level is "SQL Server 2017 (140)" on prod and dev
2b - Not used QUERYTRACEON before so this will take some time - if you think it's worth the research time?

Comment: Legacy Cardinality Estimation is OFF on all databases so using the newer 2014+ CE engine.